# Getting single file instead of multiple file

Tags: laravel, file

My form code is like below.

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.jobs.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
@csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My controller code is like below

```
public function store( Request $request ) {
    
        $images = $request->file('images');

        dd($images);
}
```

But I am getting below output.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looping over your `$images`?

Comment: try  ```$images = $request->images;``` ```dd($images);``` you will get multiple images

Comment: Thanks @matheenulla. I am getting same result. Thanks.

Comment: It's happening in ```local``` or in ```server```?

Comment: weird situation. Please check with any kind of validation you are using for images or clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
    $images = $request->file('images');
    dd($images);
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        // Perform necessary validation and processing for each file
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        // and store code
    }
    
    return "Files uploaded successfully!";
}
```

Comment: But multiple files foreach trigger

Comment: `foreach` will _not_ trigger. That's "basically" the same code as OP posted. (Anything after `dd($images);` will not be executed)

Comment: Thanks @heenakaushar. I am getting this output.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpWgF.png